# What does this UICollectionView exception mean?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

In my application using UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource and compositional layout, I saw this exception

> Thread 1: "This solver does not handle estimated items so this method
> does nothing. Are you calling this in error?"

that was thrown in dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animated).
I don't understand what it is telling me and how I should fix it. Any idea?

I do use self-sizing cells and the code works fine 99% of the time. Seems like a rare race condition.